# One camera USB causes external flash drive icon to appear in Windows 10 system tray but another camera's USB does not do so

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, snap-camera

I have been using an old Nikon Coolpix 4800 and whenever it was connected to my Windows 10 x64 Pro PC the external flash drive icon would appear in the system tray.  I would tell Windows to "eject" the device when I was ready to unplug it. I did this just yesterday. Today I connected a newer model Nikon Coolpix L830. I had to tell Windows which action should be taken when it is connected (I chose open in File Explorer) but connecting the camera does not cause the external flash drive icon to appear in the system tray.

Did the icon not appear because with the newer camera it is unnecessary to tell Windows to "eject" the external device before unplugging? Has the USB flash drive technology and/or Windows changed to make this a safe thing to do? Or is this a glitch that I need to troubleshoot?

P.S. I am running Windows 10 OS build 18363.1198. If there is a close vote because this question is a duplicate, kindly add a comment that the other answer applies to this Windows build and also to this camera's USB version, whatever that is -- I haven't been able to find that piece of info yet.

Answer (score 1):

**It's working as expected. Don't worry about it.**

---

The reason by ejecting is necessary is because your OS has a write buffer. What that means is that OS doesn't immediately write small changes to the device. Instead it waits until enough operations are queued and then performs them in one batch. This strategy improves overall write performance for the device because performing many small operations has large overhead and effectively wastes performance.

Ejecting the device flushes all buffers to disk. In case of mechanical drives (essentially HDDs) it can also prepare the device to be disconnected safely.

Your new camera either uses a protocol that doesn't support write buffering (or doesn't have it implemented) or is configured to not buffer writes by default. Without a write buffer and moving parts, a device can be safely disconnected at any moment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!